# how to access Render Result image layers python

Tags: python, scripting, image

My active image in image editor is `Render Result` image. 
How do I access the `layer` via Python (I need it to be set to `Composite` using script)

```
bpy.data.images["Render Result"].???
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to make sure the layer was 'Composite' because I will need to save the rendered image to the disk using a script. If a user previously set the layer to 'ViewLayer', I will have unwanted results.

**Solution I came up with:**

- create a new slot for Render Result image using `new_slot = image.render_slots.new()`
- set newly created slot to be active by `image.render_slots.active = new_slot`
- then `context.view_layer.use = False` which will disable layers rendering
- in `Compositing` workspace I plugged `Image` node output into `Composite` node input using `context.scene.node_tree.links.new(...)`
- lastly, I run render `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True, use_viewport=False)`.

By the end of all this, my `new_slot` won't have any `Layer` choose option (because it won't render image from scene cameras), so I can confidently save the rendered image.

Answer (score 0):

bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.layer = Composite

that may do the trick, haven't tested though

Comment: [image_settings](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.image_settings) is read only.  If this does work it may have unpredictable side effects resulting in crashes.

Comment: Thanks, @Aidan, it didn't work, but you gave me the right direction.

Comment: It's read only? I was able to change the render format and file paths via python without error.