# How I can get the pixel data of a render from a script?

Tags: rendering, scripting

I have the following blender script to get the pixel data of a render

```
project_path = os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath)
render_path = project_path + "/textures/" + collection.name
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = render_path + ".png"
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
image = bpy.data.images.load(bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
pixels = [int(value * 255) for value in image.pixels]
os.remove(bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
```

You can see I'm saving the render into a png file which later I load again so I can get the pixel data.

This is not efficient, could be possible to just get the pixel data without saving it into a file?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269494/how-to-access-render-result-image-layers-python or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2170/how-to-access-render-result-pixels-from-python-script

Comment: @lemon all those solutions require to render the result into a file, I just want to render without writing a file, I just need the pixel data in my script. Saving to a file and then parsing a png again is quite slow

Comment: sorry the first link is an error. The second one may work: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23309/19156

Comment: this looks a bit hacky, there is no official way?

Comment: 'Render result' is still empty, afaik...

Comment: you could try this one also https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248543/19156